# AppRequest: How to broadcast message?

Tags: facebook, broadcast

**Question #1:**
I could send messages to A USER of my application by using this URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/(fbid)/apprequests?message=(message)&access_token&mothod=post

But, how to send that message TO ALL USERS of my application? (aka Broadcast Message).

**Question #2**:
Ok, assume that messages has been successfully sent to all users of my application.
How do I delete that messages?

A complete PHP code is very appeciated. :)

Comment: Check out the documentation for the [`apprequests` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests).  See here for [more info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting)

Comment: A "plz send me teh codez" questions is not apprecaited :( :(